# selenium for WPE

Tags: selenium, webkit, qtwebkit, wpe

My need is to automate test cases for Wayland for WebKit(WPE) in embedded environment.

By googling and checking Stack Overflow I learned that QtWebKit provides WebDriver support for automation, so using Selenium and JSON wire protocol QtWebKit can be automated. See [GitHub for using QtWebDriver to run an application](https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver/wiki/Use-QtWebDriver-to-run-your-application).

Can I automate WPE using a QtWebKit driver?
If so, how? or if not, is there any alternative for automating WPE?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an existing WebDriver implementation for WPE that might work for you: https://github.com/Metrological/webdriver. I just found it and don't know anything about it.

A bunch of WebDriver support code recently landed upstream, but this is a separate project that is not quite ready yet. See https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=166679.